# splitting strings to columns from the end of the character string

Tags: r

I have a dataset:

```
dummydata = data.frame(code = c("Aardenburg G 18", "Loon op Zand H 262"))
```

And I want to turn it into this:

```
enddata = data.frame(municipality = c("Aardenburg", "Loon op Zand"),
                     section = c("G", "H"),
                     number = c("18", "262"))
```

Because the municipality name often has spaces in them, I have to start splitting from the end of the character string. The data always is the municipality name followed by a space, an uppercase letter, and then an integer. I looked up on the internet and stackoverflow and ran into regex lines which are totally new for me.

I managed to split the number into a different column with the following code but I cannot seem to get the uppercase letter in its own column.

```
dummydata2 = dummydata %>% 
  tidyr::separate("code", into = c("municipality", "number"), "(A-Z)|(?=[0-9])", extra = "merge", fill = "right", remove = F)
```

Anyone who can help and clarify how the regex lines work? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dummydata = data.frame(code = c("Aardenburg G 18", "Loon op Zand H 262"))

dummydata %>% 
  separate(code, into=c("municipality", "section", "number"), 
           sep=" (?=\\d+)| (?=[A-Z] \\d+)", convert = T)

#>   municipality section number
#> 1   Aardenburg       G     18
#> 2 Loon op Zand       H    262
```

Comment: Could you clarify the regex code for me?

With '?=\\d+)|' you're looking for a digit if I'm correct. However what is the function of the + and the | symbol?

could you also clarify the code after that, '(?=[A-Z] \\d+)' for me?

Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, @stefaneke! `\\d` means digit. `\\d+` means 1 or more digits. `|` means the logical `or`. `?=` means looking ahead. `[A-Z]` means a capital letter. For more information, please see: https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_strings.pdf. Hope I was clear!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
require(stringr)
endata <- dummydata %>%
  mutate(section = word(code, -2),
         number = word(code, -1))
```

changed a little your syntax, used `word` function from `stringr` instead. It selects the nth word, but by indicating a negative index, it reverses the order from the last to the first word.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Replace the last space with semicolon and then do it again.  Now it can be read as semicolon separated strings.  Note that "(.*) " matches the longest string until and including the last space and \1; says to replace it with the part in parenthesis followed by semicolon. Backslashes need to be doubled within quotes. No packages are used.

```
dummydata |>
  transform(code = sub("(.*) ", "\\1;", code)) |>
  transform(code = sub("(.*) ", "\\1;", code)) |>
  with(read.table(text = code, sep = ";", 
    col.names = c("municipality", "section", "number")))
```

giving:

```
  municipality section number
1   Aardenburg       G     18
2 Loon op Zand       H    262
```

**2)** Another way to use sub is to match each field and replace the spaces between them with semicolons giving the same result.  This uses one fewer sub but the regular expression is a bit more complex. \w+ matches one or more word characters and \d+ matches one or more digits. \1 refers to the first capture group, i.e. the part matched by the portion within the first parenthesis in the first argument.  \2 and \3 match the second and third capture groups. No packages are used.

```
dummydata |>
  transform(code = sub("^(.*) (\\w+) (\\d+)$", "\\1;\\2;\\3", code)) |>
  with(read.table(text = code, sep = ";", 
    col.names = c("municipality", "section", "number")))
```

**3)** We can reduce (2) to a single read.pattern statement using gsubfn package.  The pattern is the same as in (2).

```
library(gsubfn)

read.pattern(text = dummydata$code, pattern = "^(.*) (\\w+) (\\d+)$",
  col.names = c("municipality", "section", "number"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `regex` is an overkill:

```
enddata <- strsplit(dummydata$code, " ") |> 
  lapply(
    \(x) data.frame(
      municipality  = paste(head(x, -2), collapse = " "), 
      section = tail(x, 2)[1], 
      number = tail(x, 1)
    )
  )
enddata <- do.call(rbind, enddata)

#   municipality section number
# 1   Aardenburg       G     18
# 2 Loon op Zand       H    262
```